# Unable to mask property using Log4j2 Rewrite appender and PropertiesRewritePolicy

Tags: apache-camel, log4j2

I have an apache camel webapp running in a tomcat container that uses log4j2 to log. I am using xml DSL to define routes. I am trying to mask certain properties before they get logged into log files by making use of Rewrite appender and PropertiesRewritePolicy. However this doesnot work.
Below is my route definition which sets a "password" property

```
<c:route context="abc" type="authentication" id="Authentication Route" routeType="INTERNAL" logMask="true">
    <from uri="direct:authentication_route" />
     <!-- Code to get the access token -->
     <setProperty propertyName="password">
         <jsonpath>$.access_token</jsonpath>
     </setProperty>
     <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Test for masking password: ${property[password]}"/>
     <!-- Some other code -->
 </c:route>
```

And my log4j.xml is as below. The rewrite appender sets(or rather should set) the password property to xxxxxxx before passing it to the roll-by-size-and-time appender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [THREAD ID=%t] %-5p %C:%L - %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">logs</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_FILE_BASE_NAME">AppLog</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <!-- ###  output log to console  ### -->
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" charset="UTF-8"/>
        </Console>

        <!-- ###  Rolling file setup to zip file if log exceeds 50MB or to rollover each day  ### -->
        <RollingFile name="roll-by-size-and-time"
                     fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE_BASE_NAME}.log"
                     filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE_BASE_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz"
                     ignoreExceptions="false"
                     immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout charset="UTF-8">
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20">
                <Delete basePath="${LOG_DIR}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE_BASE_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="20d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <Rewrite name="rewrite">
            <!-- LogInterceptor>CustomLogInterceptor</LogInterceptor -->
            <AppenderRef ref="roll-by-size-and-time"></AppenderRef>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <PropertiesRewritePolicy>
                <Property name="password">xxxxxxxx</Property>
            </PropertiesRewritePolicy>
        </Rewrite>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.camel" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.jboss.stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter" level="FATAL"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.slf4j" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoreBase" level="WARN"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="ERROR"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="ERROR"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager" level="ERROR"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>       
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, in the log I still see the password getting printed ... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration says that you want to add a new property named "password" with a value of "xxxxxxxx" to the ThreadContextMap. Somehow I don't think that is what you intended.

I suspect you either want to use the replace attribute of the PatternLayout or the replace pattern converter such as

```
%replace{%msg}{password:\s+(\S+)}{password: *****}
```